# How to show the title with "multiple marks" in Vega lite?

Tags: charts, vega-lite, vega

I am using this Stacked Bar Chart Example at the link: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/stacked-bar-chart/

[image]

But I can't figure out how to show the field title on axis x and y.

I want to show the title x and y below.

[image]

Is there a way to display the label title on the x and y axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a title attribute.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic stacked bar chart example.",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"x": 0, "y": 28, "c": 0}, {"x": 0, "y": 55, "c": 1},
        {"x": 1, "y": 43, "c": 0}, {"x": 1, "y": 91, "c": 1},
        {"x": 2, "y": 81, "c": 0}, {"x": 2, "y": 53, "c": 1},
        {"x": 3, "y": 19, "c": 0}, {"x": 3, "y": 87, "c": 1},
        {"x": 4, "y": 52, "c": 0}, {"x": 4, "y": 48, "c": 1},
        {"x": 5, "y": 24, "c": 0}, {"x": 5, "y": 49, "c": 1},
        {"x": 6, "y": 87, "c": 0}, {"x": 6, "y": 66, "c": 1},
        {"x": 7, "y": 17, "c": 0}, {"x": 7, "y": 27, "c": 1},
        {"x": 8, "y": 68, "c": 0}, {"x": 8, "y": 16, "c": 1},
        {"x": 9, "y": 49, "c": 0}, {"x": 9, "y": 15, "c": 1}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["x"],
          "sort": {"field": "c"},
          "field": "y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "x"}
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true, "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "c"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "x", "zindex": 1, "title":"x"},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y", "zindex": 1, "title":"y"}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "x"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1, "offset": -1},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"}
        },
        "update": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]